# Error creating bean with name 'BitronixTransactionManager' defined in URL

Tags: spring, tomcat8

I created two tomcat instances in single OS(windows). when i ran second instance i got below error.

```
2018-07-04 13:11:22,859 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.ContextLoader [ContextLoader.java:331] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'BitronixTransactionManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208/webapps/mfsmiddleware/WEB-INF/lib/a.b.c.d.e-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/spring/jbpm-a-b.xml]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager]: Factory method 'getTransactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is bitronix.tm.utils.InitializationException: cannot open disk journal
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]

Caused by: bitronix.tm.utils.InitializationException: cannot open disk journal

Caused by: java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file
```

Comment: It seems a concurrent issue; there is one file locked by another process

Comment: thanks Angelo, yes the issue is concurrent but how to avoid
i need to run two tomcats in single os(windows)

Comment: how did you configure the bitronix journal? I guess you should configure it carefully. Give a look here https://github.com/bitronix/btm/wiki/Transaction-manager-configuration above all in this section https://github.com/bitronix/btm/wiki/Transaction-manager-configuration#Journal_Settings

Comment: i am getting this exception while starting second tomcat instance. first tomcat instance started successfully. still does it conf problem?

Comment: Yes because I guess both tomcat try to write the bitronix journal in same location. You should configure them in order to avoid the write in same location

Comment: thanks angelo, we didnt configured that btm log any where. i thought betronix will asign some file locaton [btmlog]

Comment: can please tell me how to assign btmlog location

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue caused by the locked btm.tlog file, please delete the file and restart the service. This action should resolve the problem